# df.assign(np.nan) is not nan

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am trying to initially assign a nan values of a column then I will replace the nan values based on some conditions. However I faced some thing weird. when checking if this column == np.nan, it doesn't enter the if condition, instead it enters the else. any ideas why is this happening? should I check with other way?

```
for _, g in  df.groupby(['x1','x2']):
  g=g.assign(cluster=np.nan)
  for j in range(g.shape[0]):
          
          
          if (g["cluster"].iloc[j]==np.nan):
              print("in first if nan")
            
              cluster_name=str(cluster)+str(c)
              c=c+1
              g["cluster"].iloc[j]=cluster_name
          else:
            print("not else")
            print(g["cluster"].iloc[j])
            print(type(g["cluster"].iloc[j]))
            cluster_name=g["cluster"].iloc[j]
```

Comment: try `np.isnan` or `pandas.isna` instead of the comparison

Comment: Interesting question though. Turns out the IEEE 754 standard requires that `NaN != X` for all possible values of X, including NaN, so `NaN == NaN` should return False. [Discussion here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754)